# Module not found: Can't resolve '@styles/globals.css'

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I was following a tutorial on `next.js`, I have now decided to start my own project, but I get the error `Module not found: Can't resolve '@styles/globals.css'`

On the tutorial project I get no error:

**Tutorial Code**

```
import '@styles/globals.css';

export const metadata = {
    title: "Tutorial ",
    description: "Welcome to the Tutorial"
}

const RootLayout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

But On my own project I get the error

**My Code**

```
import '@styles/globals.css';

export const metadata = {
    title: "Application 2",
    description: "Welcome to application 2"
}


const RootLayout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <html>
            <body>
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

Both next.config files are identical in terms of lines of code

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        appDir: true,
        serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"],
    },
    images: {
        domains: ['lh3.googleusercontent.com'],
    },
    webpack(config) {
        config.experiments = {
            ...config.experiments,
            topLevelAwait: true,
        }
        return config
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

...but the only difference is in my code there seems to be an issue with the last line `module.exports = nextConfig`. I cant seem to figure out what it is.

Problem visualised - You can see in the tutorial code, `module` is recognised but not recognised in mine

**Tutorial code**
[image]

**My Code**
[image]

You can see the word `module` is not highlighted in my code

Answer (score 3):

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases 

in order to make it works, you need to put / after @:
@/styles.globals.css

OR if you don't want to,

you need to delete '/' in jsconfig.json file
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["./*"]
        }
      }
    }
    
to
    
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
          "@*": ["./*"]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).