# Migrate to TypeScript leads to error Can't resolve '@/styles/globals.css'

Tags: css, typescript, next.js

I'm playing around with the boilerplate template and found this strange issue when trying to use TypeScript with the default NextJS configuration. I mean, by changing the file from `.js` to `.tsx` / `.tsx`. I tried several versions of NextJS 13 up to the latest. And also the TypeScript 5 and 4.

```
error - ./pages/_app.tsx:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/styles/globals.css'
> 1 | import '@/styles/globals.css'
  2 | import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react'
  3 |
  4 | export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

My VSCode cannot find the file when I command+click it, but when I changed the file to `Globals.module.css,` it could. But the error still exists: module not found.

Any pointers?

GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/10322).

Related:
[Module not found: Can't resolve '@styles/globals.css'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76372495/module-not-found-cant-resolve-styles-globals-css)

Answer (score 0):

changing the file extension from `.js` to `.ts` / `.tsx` is not enough you need to install `TypeScript` in your project, also make sure to add `tsconfig.json` with the right configurations and ensure that the `baseUrl` and `paths` options are correct, something like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    /* ... other configs */
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@/public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/components": ["components"],
      "@/store/*": ["store/*"],
      "@/store": ["store"],
      "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["lib/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**BUT:** I would recommend you to bootstrap your project using [npx create-next-app@latest](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/create-next-app)
and chose TypeScript when it asks you: `Would you like to use TypeScript? › No / Yes`

Comment: I did. Those are generated by NextJS.

Comment: I have bootstrapped a new project with the default configs and it worked, idk what might be wrong in your project setup, I need to do some debugging and see what is happening,  so can you please create a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: I mean this template https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/nextjs-boilerplate

Comment: I tried to set up a new project using: `npx create-next-app@latest` and kept the import alias as default for app/pages directory it worked as expected. if you could push your project to GitHub with the issue, it would help me troubleshoot the issue better

Comment: Ok, this is kinda annoying and great at the same time. The latest boilerplate template already defaulted to TypeScript and Tailwind :D

Comment: It's a private repo, i can invite you if you want